# manipulating variable and retrieving report

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to work out a problem and need some help. I have 3 types of users (T8XXXXX, P9XXXXX and XXXXX) each of these users have different elements and as such has a different report. The top two if statements work, as far as opening the reports, one report is blank and the third fails all together. I'm not really sure how to solve this, and am hoping for some help from professionals. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Private Sub cmdPrintIndRep_Click()
Dim strUser As String
strUser = Forms.frmsupresults.subfrmUsrRes!UserName
        If Left(strUser, 2) Like "t8" Then
            DoCmd.OpenReport "FedInvest - ISSR Recertification Report", acViewPreview
            ElseIf Left(strUser, 2) Like "p9" Then
                DoCmd.OpenReport "Courts - ISSR Recertification Report", acViewPreview
            Else Left(strUser, 2) not Like "p9" and not like "t8"" Then
                DoCmd.OpenReport "FedInvest - ISSR Internal Users Recertification Report", acViewPreview
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: are there any error messages? if so, what do they say?

Comment: I commented out the three if statements, the third has the syntax (not sure how to fix), but if I comment that out, each one pulls a report, just one has no data as it failed the if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I'm no professional but hopefully I can help.

I adjusted the definition of `strUser` by using a reference to referring to controls found [here](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm).

Assuming there are only 3 types of users, I simply removed the last `if` statement. If it is not the 1st type, nor the 2nd type, it must be the 3rd type of user.

Lastly, we should use `=` instead of `Like` in the conditions for the `if` statements.

```
Private Sub cmdPrintIndRep_Click()

Dim strUser As String
strUser = Forms!frmsupresults!subfrmUsrRes.Form!UserName

    If Left(strUser, 2) = "t8" Or Left(strUser, 2) = "T8" Then
        DoCmd.OpenReport "FedInvest - ISSR Recertification Report", acViewPreview
    ElseIf Left(strUser, 2) = "p9" Or Left(strUser, 2) = "P9" Then
        DoCmd.OpenReport "Courts - ISSR Recertification Report", acViewPreview
    Else
        DoCmd.OpenReport "FedInvest - ISSR Internal Users Recertification Report", _ 
                         acViewPreview
    End If
End Sub
```

As far as your reports being blank, what is their [Record Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821454.aspx)?

Comment: I've got individual queries set for the record source, the not showing issue was related to a filter set in the query. The code you did up here solved the problem. Thanks for your help.